# Will spanning my drives format them both in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have currently got a Seagate 1TB hard drive (not in use) and the WD 4TB hard drive (in use). The WD hard drive has just failed and I am getting it replaced.

I wish to use 'spanning' to combine the space of the hard drives to expand and get more storage space. I am currently waiting for my replacement WD.

If I setup the Seagate as a normal drive and start using it, when I get my WD will I be able to span it and keep the data on the Seagate, or will it get formatted.

Comment: Do you really need that much contiguous storage space? Spanning is really just asking for data loss, much like RAID0. To answer your question, you need to add the method you’d use. Onboard RAID? Microsoft Dynamic Disks?

Comment: @DanielB I would be using Microsoft Dynamic Disks using Disk Manager (JBOD)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you span using a raid controller, you will have to format the new partition created, thus all data is lost.

If you use Windows to convert a normal disk to a dynamic disk, you can then attach more harddrives as storage and the disk is not formatted. But as a downside, your partitions will only be visible to a windows installation.

Also, you cannot convert it back to a normal disk without a reformat.

Answer (score 0):

As you will use Windows dynamic volumes, you should be able to create the spanned volume  when you get the replacement WD drive without losing data. 
However, if you need to convert the volume from dynamic back to basic you will have to reformat the drives. If there is a problem with your OS there is a very high probability that all the data will be lost as the spanned volume is handled by Windows. It would be significantly safer for your data if you just use the HDDs as two separate physical basic discs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll keep the data, but if any of the drives fail, then  you'll lose everything - Even your OS won't boot.